# How to use context in React Component class after calling Gatsby createPage

Tags: javascript, node.js, gatsby

I've called this function in my gatsby-node.js file.

```
createPage({
        path: `/article/`,
        component: path.resolve(`./src/pages/article.js`),
        // The context is passed as props to the component as well
        // as into the component's GraphQL query.
        context: {
            craftercmsData
        },
    })
```

```
class IndexPage extends React.Component {

    constructor(crafterCmsData) {
        //how do I access my context data
    }

    render = () => {

    }
```

How do I access context in my IndexPage class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context` is available as a `props` (as `pageContext`), so you can easily access it using rather than a functional component or a class-based one, but it will be only available at `./src/pages/article.js`:

```
function IndexPage(props) {
  console.log("your context is", props.pageContext);
  return <h1>Hello</h1>;
}
```

Or, following your class-based component:

class IndexPage extends React.Component {

```
class IndexPage extends React.Component {
  console.log("your context is", this.props.pageContext);
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello</h1>;
  }
}
```

Useful resources:

- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/
- https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 0):

For Gatsby add the GlobalContext to the gatsby-browser.js file.

```
/**
 * Implement Gatsby's Browser APIs in this file.
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/browser-apis/
 */

// You can delete this file if you're not using it
import React from "react";
import GlobalContextProvider from './src/components/layout/GlobalContext';


export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
    return (
        <GlobalContextProvider >
            {element}
        </GlobalContextProvider>
    )
};
```